# Sharing TeamDrive with Contractors?

Tags: google-workspace, google-drive-shared-drive

I am going to migrate onto Google Workspace. I will create several TeamDrives under there, where my contractors (photographer etc.) will upload the files they created.

1. They will use their own gmail account, not with an email of my company's domain.
2. In personal Google Drive, when someone shares a folder/file with me, those are still owned by them. Therefore, when they delete on their own personal account, those files are also removed from my side. **As per my understanding, TeamDrive sorts out this issue. When they upload a file/folder into a TeamDrive using their own gmail account, the ownership of these are taken by the TeamDrive and protected from deletion in the future.**

Can someone help me to clarify these questions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation available about Shared Drives, which I think is the feature you are referring to, if a user outside of your organization contributes to your organization's shared drives, the content uploaded, created or edited is **transferred** to it and belongs to the shared drives uploaded.

The documentation says the following: "*Any work an external user contributes (for example, edits to, creating, or uploading a file) is transferred to and owned by the domain that created the shared drive.*"

Here is the [link](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7212025#zippy=%2Cwhat-can-you-do-with-shared-drives:%7E:text=Any%20work%20an%20external%20user%20contributes) in case you need it.

In addition, the external user shouldn't be able to remove the file unless the privilege given is Manager or Content Manager; to upload Contributor privilege is enough. Check the [documentation](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7337554) about the access levels.

Comment: Perfect. That’s what I’m clearly trying to learn.

Answer (score 1):

Google Shared Drive (former Team Drive) is suitable for transferring ownership of Google Drive files. Files on Google Shared Drive do not have an individual owner.

Another possible option is to use Google Forms to upload files to Google Drive. When using the apps script or [Google Forms add-on](https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/form_uploads_manager/756774028129), these files can be automatically renamed, organized into folders on Google Drive and Google Shared Drive.

Comment: Perfect. That’s what I’m clearly trying to learn.